# Sumproduct VBA returning a type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I am very new to VBA, so I'm certain that what I'm missing is very simple and something someone with more experience wouldn't overlook.

My code is as follow:

```
Sub test_match()
Sheets("Course Cascade").Select
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim rfirst As Long
Dim cfirst As Long
Dim rlast As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim rownum As Long
Dim csum As Long
Dim rowTerm As Long
Dim k As Integer
Dim rabove As Long
Dim ccount As Long
Dim clkup As Long

r = 107: c = 7: rowTerm = 106: ccount = 3: cfirst = 7: csum = c - 1: k = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("e107:e1661"), ">0"): clkup = 5

If Cells(r, ccount) <= WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((Range(Cells(47, c), Cells(74, c))), (--Range("CourseCascadeRow").Value = Cells(r, clkup))) Then
                Cells(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Index("CourseCascadeCt", WorksheetFunction.Match(Range(Cells(r, 5)), Range("CourseCascadeCtRow"), 0), _
                WorksheetFunction.Match(Range(Cells(106, c)), Range("CourseCascadeCol"), 0) / WorksheetFunction.Index("CourseCascadeCt", WorksheetFunction.Match(Range(Cells(r, 5)), Range("CourseCascadeCtRow"), 0), _
                WorksheetFunction.Match(Range(Cells(106, c)), Range("CourseCascadeCol"), 0))), 0)
```

There is an else argument in there too, but I've isolated the type mismatch error to this part of the Sumproduct formula: --Range("CourseCascadeRow").Value = Cells(r, clkup))) .  The ".value" at the end of the range has been something I've tried adding and removing with no change.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I know the code is ugly...

Thanks!

Comment: vba does not like the `--`.  You will need to do something else to get the array of `1,0`.  You can loop the range and create a variant array then use that array in the sumproduct.

Comment: You can try: `ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=INDEX(--" & Range("CourseCascadeRow").Address(1,1,xlA1,1) & "=" & Cells(r, clkup) & ",)")` in its place.

Comment: You could consider splitting that up so it's debuggable...

Comment: It also appears the your numerator and denominator are the same which will result in `1` or if it errors `0`.

Comment: @ScottCraner---could of quick questions if you don't mind.  The "ActiveSheet" portion.  This is in a module and will be run when a user clicks a command button on another sheet.  Will the Activesheet.Evaluate still work?  Additionally, can you explain the Address portion?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Then replace ActiveSheet with the correct sheet `Worksheets("...")`

Comment: The address is just that it returns the address as a string.

Comment: @ScottCraner--I tried to put your code in using the Worksheets method you suggested as follows "If Cells(r, ccount) <= Worksheets("Course Cascade").Evaluate("=INDEX(--" & Range("CourseCascadeRow").Address(1, 1, xlA1, 1) & "=" & Cells(r, clkup) & ",)")".  However, I still got the type mismatch error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

BTW as [@TimWilliams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608726/sumproduct-vba-returning-a-type-mismatch-error#comment107228053_60608726) commented, split it up and limit the number of worksheet functions:

```
Sub kjlkjlkj()

    Dim CCR As Variant
    CCR = Range("CourseCascadeRow")

    Dim vl As Double
    vl = 0#



    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(CCR, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(CCR, 2)
            vl = vl + (Cells(47, c) * .Cells(74, c) * (-1 * CBool(CCR(i, j) = Cells(r, clkup))))
        Next j
    Next i


    If .Cells(r, ccount) <= vl Then
        Dim rw As Variant
        rw = Application.Match(Range(Cells(r, 5)), Range("CourseCascadeCtRow"), 0)

        Dim clm As Variant
        clm = Application.Match(Range(Cells(106, c)), Range("CourseCascadeCol"), 0)

        Cells(r, c.value = 0

        If Not (IsError(rw) Or IsError(clm)) Then
            Cells(r, c).Value = Range("CourseCascadeCt").Cells(rw, c).Value / Range("CourseCascadeCt").Cells(rw, c).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This will help with the debugging.

Comment: Hi Scott,  I think this is very close, but I'm still not quite there.  So here's my problem....I have 7 courses that are going to be initally offered at different points of time, but afterwards will be offered monthly (or 4 times per academic term).  So, if the first course is offered initally in Summer 2020, that will be the first time it's offered, and should only return 1 for the combination of Course 1 and Summer 2020 and count 1.  However, this is returning a value for every time course 1 shows up, not just for count 1.   I can upload my whole file if you'd like.